# Phone gap: Play captured video in standard HTML5 player

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins

I created an Angular app wrapped inside a Phonegap app. I've created a directive, which is a button. When one clicks the button, the video library is returned and a video can be selected. On callback, I receive the video URI (I'm testing on iOS, something like file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/..../tmp/video.MOV).

I'd like to give users a preview of the video they selected, so I create a video tag on this callback:

```
$('#test').append('<video controls preload="auto" width="340" height="340" onclick="this.play();"><source src="' + videoURI + '" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
```

The video tag is created successfully, and a play button is visible. Nothing happens when I click the play button, however. The video won't play. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way to play a local video inside a Phonegap application?

Comment: What version of Cordova and file plugin? Have you tried attaching the Safari web inspector to look for an error?

Comment: I'm using the Phonegap Developer app on iOS, so I'm not sure how to get into the web inspector? I use the latest version of Cordova (5.1.1). I've tried setting the source to an MP4 file on the web, and that one does play.

Comment: Check this http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: Turns out it's due to the app I used to test (Cordova Browser). It works using the PhoneGap Developer app.